# StartActivity in a Thread

Tags: android

Why does MainActivity not start after 1 sec?

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    supportActionBar?.hide()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
    Thread {
       Thread.sleep(1000)
       println("test")
       runOnUiThread {
           startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
           this.finish()
       }
   }
}
```

Does anyone could help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thread.run()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run()). You have to run the Thread.

Answer (score 0):

add  thread.start(); after your thread curly braces. or you can follow my code

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                doprogress();
                nectactivity();
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}

private void nectactivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SpalshScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}

private void doprogress() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
           
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new task flag

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```